# python dictionary weird behavior

Tags: python, dictionary

1. I can't understand why, when c=2 and c=3, the dict2['A']=1 and dict2['A']=4 respectively and not 0, even though I make dict2 to be equal to dict1, where dict1['A']=0? Why does dict1['A'] change from 0? I don't change any of the dict1 variables!
2. Why does dict3 show correct values within the loop, but only shows values from the last iteration 3 after the loop is finished.

Thank you very much.

```
import collections

def main():


    dict1 = collections.OrderedDict()
    dict2 = collections.OrderedDict()
    dict3 = collections.OrderedDict()

    dict1['A'] = 0
    dict1['B'] = 0
    dict1['C'] = 0

    for c in [1, 2, 3]:
        print('c=' + str(c))
        dict2 = dict1
        print('dict1A=' + str(dict1['A']))
        print('dict2A=' + str(dict2['A']))
        if c == 1:
            dict2['A'] = 1
            dict2['B'] = 2
            dict2['C'] = 3
        elif c ==2:
            dict2['A'] = 4
            dict2['B'] = 5
            dict2['C'] = 6
        elif c ==3:
            dict2['A'] = 7
            dict2['B'] = 8
            dict2['C'] = 9
        dict3['c' + str(c)] = dict2
        print('dict2A=' + str(dict2['A']))
        print('dict' + str(c) + 'A=' + str(dict3['c' + str(c)]['A']))
        print('dict' + str(c) + 'B=' + str(dict3['c' + str(c)]['B']))
        print('dict' + str(c) + 'C=' + str(dict3['c' + str(c)]['C']))

    print('dict3-c1A='+ str(dict3['c1']['A']))
    print('dict3-c2B=' + str(dict3['c2']['B']))
    print('dict3-c3C=' + str(dict3['c3']['C']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
c=1
dict1A=0
dict2A=0
dict2A=1
dict1A=1
dict1B=2
dict1C=3
c=2
dict1A=1
dict2A=1
dict2A=4
dict2A=4
dict2B=5
dict2C=6
c=3
dict1A=4
dict2A=4
dict2A=7
dict3A=7
dict3B=8
dict3C=9
dict3-c1A=7
dict3-c2B=8
dict3-c3C=9
```

* EDIT ***
Thank you very much for the answers. I didn't know the '=' operation for dictionaries was not the same as for variables. I found out and as was suggested by g.d.d.c, that the copy() is what I wanted:

```
        dict2 = dict1.copy()
```

Comment: Your edit says that the `=` operation is different for dicts compared to other variables, but it isn't! Try experimenting with a list or a string or a number, they will all act in the same manner as the dict did here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `dict2 = dict1` you replace the name which previously existed as an empty `OrderedDict` and tell the interpreter instead to use `dict2` to refer to the same `Object` that exists in the name `dict1`.  You can do a couple of things to work around this:

```
# copy
dict2 = dict1.copy()
# update dict 2
dict2.update(dict1.iteritems())
```

Answer (score 3):

1. This is how the Python object model works. by saying `dict2 = dict1`, what in essence happens during the first loop iteration is that the original dict2 object is discarded, and dict2 now refers to the same *underlying object as dict 1*. During subsequent loop iterations, the `dict2 = dict1` statement has no effect since `dict1` and `dict2` are already both pointing at the same underlying object.
2. Your print statements for dict3 are one level of indentation further out than your loop body; they are not part of the loop, and therefore only execute once the loop is finished.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict2 = dict1
```

This doesn't erase the contents of `dict2` and fill it with the contents of `dict1`. This makes the names `dict1` and `dict2` refer to the same object. Anything you do to `dict2` affects `dict1`, because they're the same thing.

If you want a new dict, make a new dict:

```
dict2 = collections.OrderedDict()
```

If you want to clear the old dict, clear it, but that's probably not what you want:

```
dict2.clear()
```